# Run code if URL parameter APPEARS more than once

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, url

I feel this is so bloody easy but I just can't figure it out.

See code below:

```
if(getUrlParameter('style') && getUrlParameter('style') != "all"){
    var type = getUrlParameter('style');
  }
  else 
  if (getUrlParameter('type') == "res") {
    var type = "Homes";
  } else if (getUrlParameter('type') == "con") {
    var type = "Condos";
  } else if (getUrlParameter('type') == "lnd") {
    var type = "Land";
  } else if (getUrlParameter('type') == "mul") {
    var type = "Income Properties";
  } else if (getUrlParameter('type') == "twn") {
    var type = "Townhomes";
  } else if (getUrlParameter('type') == "com") {
    var type = "Commercial Properties";
  } else if (getUrlParameter('type') == "com") && (getUrlParameter('type') == "com") {
    var type = "Commercial Properties";
  }
```

I want to have it where if 'type' shows up in the URL twice or more, such as "type=res&type=con", that it would return a var equaling "Real Estate".

Comment: The first step I would try is simply `console.log(getUrlParameter('type'))` and see what comes back and work from there.

Answer (score 1):

[`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) is a more convenient way to access a query string.

To strictly answer your question: Once you have an `URLSearchParams` object, you can check the `length` property of the array returned by `getAll('type')`.

Applying it to your code, you are looking for this

```
params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
var type;

if (params.getAll("type").length == 1) {
    // If only one type parameter, use your current code
    let typeValue = params.get("type");

    if (typeValue == "res") {
        type = "Homes";
    } else if (typeValue == "con") {
        type = "Condos";
    } else if (typeValue == "lnd") {
        type = "Land";
    } else if (typeValue == "mul") {
        type = "Income Properties";
    } else if (typeValue == "twn") {
        type = "Townhomes";
    } else if (typeValue == "com") {
        type = "Commercial Properties";
    } 
} else {
    // More than one or not defined, return a generic string
    type = "Real Estate";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what getUrlParameter does exactly but what you could try is something like this:

```
var params = new URLSearchParams('type=res&type=com');
if (params.getAll('type').includes('com') && params.getAll('type').includes('res')) {
    //foo
}
```

Comment: Yeah the thing is 'type' can equal a ton of things. So I'd have to create a ton of code. I just want it where if 'type' appears twice in the URL, there is a specific var for that event if that makes sense.

Comment: if(window.location.href.indexOf("/search") > -1){
   var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
        var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1),
            sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
            sParameterName,
            i;

        for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
            sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

            if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
                return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);
            }
        }
    };

Comment: ^ That's what that function does btw

Comment: It's not working. If you want to see the page it is supposed to be on: https://www.bothellhomes.com/search/results/3qz/?city=Bothell&neighborhood=all&type=res&type=con&type=mul&list_price_min=50000&list_price_max=all&area_min=all&beds_min=all&baths_min=all&lot_size_min=all&style=all&short_sale=all&school_district=all&waterfront=all&view=all&architecture=all&year_built_min=all&year_built_max=all&parking_spaces_min=all&parking_type=all&master_on_main=all

Comment: Link to the JS file running it: https://u.realgeeks.media/lookinwa/js/listingresultsheader.js

Comment: Better URL. This one should say Bothell Real Estate For Sale, Not Bothell Homes For Sale. Based on 'type' showing up multiple times in the URL: https://www.bothellhomes.com/search/results/50/?city=Bothell&neighborhood=all&type=res&type=con&type=mul&list_price_min=50000&list_price_max=all&area_min=all&beds_min=all&baths_min=all&lot_size_min=all&style=all&short_sale=all&school_district=all&waterfront=all&view=all&architecture=all&year_built_min=all&year_built_max=all&parking_spaces_min=all&parking_type=all&master_on_main=all

Comment: @KevinBoroumand My comment referred to using `params` as shown in the answer, not your `getUrlParameter` function, yours only returns the first instance (and would never enter the last `else if` if the first one matches). You have to change the flow of your logic.